# Generics for data structure that stores key value pair

Tags: java, generics, data-structures

Given I wanted to write my own data structure, as far as I understand, if I wanted to use generics I would do `public class myDataStructure<E>`. However, If I wanted to write a data structure that stored data in a key value pair, how would I use generics? Could I do `public class myOtherDataStructure<E, Integer>` for example, and use `<E>` the same way it was used with `myDataStructure`?

Also, I don't want to use `HashMap` or anything similar. The point here is that I want to understand what I would do if I wanted to define my own data structure.

Comment: If you need multiple type parameters, just add them to the class definition, eg `public class MyClass<T,R>`

Comment: So what I proposed in the question would work?

Comment: No, it won't compile. you can't specify the actually type in the class definition. `Integer` type that you are specifying in the question, has to be specified while creating the object

Comment: What if I always wanted the second type to be `Integer`?

Comment: You can enforce that by using the `extends` clause,`myOtherDataStructure<E, T extends Integer>`

Comment: `T extends Integer` makes little sense, as `Integer` is final. If you know your values are always Integers, you don't need to include that as a generic type at all: `MyOtherDataStructure<K>`, and then declare: `public Integer get(K key)` and `public void put(K key, Integer value)`

Answer (score 0):

If you know your values are only going to be integers, then the value type should not be a generic type. Your data structure can look like this:

```
public class MyOtherDataStructure<K> {

    public void put(K key, Integer value) {...}

    public Integer get(K key) {...}

}
```